# How to write a hexadecimal literally to file?

Tags: c++, hex, binaryfiles

I have a little problem, I want to write something like that `0xff` to a file, and I have done it:

```
ofstream file;
file.open(this->dbFile, ios::app | ios::binary);
const char prefix = 0xff;
file.write(&prefix, sizeof(char));
```

The previous example works well, but this is not my issue.
I want to write the previous example with writing the hexadecimal literally like the following:

```
ofstream file;
file.open(this->dbFile, ios::app | ios::binary);
file.write((const char*)0xff, sizeof(char));
```

But unfortunately, there is a runtime error occurs with the second example.
I know there's something wrong with the data conversion, but what is it?

Comment: I see many inconsequesnces: binary mode, and text data etc ... numbers are just numbers, no dec, hex, oct and other

Comment: cast `(const char*)0xff` has not sense. Use first variant

Comment: `file.put(0xFF)`?

Comment: @molbdnilo: I think `put()` function works well as I want, but is it also suitable for writing hexadecimal (binary) to file?

Comment: @LionKing Numbers aren't hexadecimal (or decimal, or binary, or ...) Do you want to write the number `0xff` (that is, 255), or the string `"0xff"`? (Or perhaps the string `"ff"`?)

Comment: @molbdnilo: I want to write a binary representation of `0xff` like the binary data of BMP file for instance.

Comment: @LionKing Then `file.put(0xFF)` is what you want (You could also write `file.put(255)` or `file.put(0377)`, or even `file.put(0b11111111)` if your compiler supports it).

Comment: @molbdnilo: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

first `char` is often used as a synonym for the non existing type `byte`, however you could easily make your own using statement like

```
#include <cstdint>
using byte_t = int8_t;
```

Consider this line `file.write((const char*)0xff, sizeof(char));` as `ostream::Write(const byte_t* pointerToArrayOfData, std::streamsize sizeOfData)`. `0xFF` is the data you want to write but not an address of an array holding your data. `sizeof(char)=sizeof(byte_t)=1` can be neglected, the method is designed to write single bytes. However you can use this to serialize custom types like

```
struct Point { int8_t x, y; };
array<Point, 4> myRectangle {/* */};
file.write(&myRectangle, sizeof(Point) * array.size());
file.write(&myRectangle, sizeof(array<Point, 4>));
```

Note this is platform dependent and you should always consider the generated file can only be read on the same system you created it. If you want to transfer binary data please consider some abstractions like protobuf.

**TLDR;**

```
using byte_t = char;
void write_binary_data(std::ostream& ostream, byte_t* data, size_t count)
{
  ostream.write(data, count);
}

using binary_data_t = std::vector<byte_t>;
void write_binary_data(std::ostream& ostream, const binary_data_t data)
{
  write_binary_data(ostream, data.data(), data.size());
}

ofstream file;
file.open(this->dbFile, ios::app | ios::binary);
write_binary_data(file, { 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF });
```

Comment: As of C++17 we do have `std::byte`.